# How to customize Angular Material stepper component showing label at the top?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material stepper. I found stepper label position left, bottom. I want to stepper label position top of the stepper and
stepper circle icon shown below. Here is the stepper example for label position bottom.

[stepper-label-position-bottom-example.html](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lyqkeqmnvpb?file=app%2Fstepper-label-position-bottom-example.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That option is not given by angular material team, you can fixed that problem using custom css.

```
/** custom CSS as per your :required */
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
    height: auto;
    padding: 24px;
}
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header .mat-step-label {
    padding: 0px 0px 16px !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header:not(:first-child)::before, ::ng-deep .mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header:not(:last-child)::after{
    top: 68px !important;
}
```

[Stackblitz link goes here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fp4j17-933rcz?file=app%2Fstepper-label-position-bottom-example.css)

Answer (score 2):

It is actually much simpler.

In your global styles (styles.css) just add:

```
.mat-step-header {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rlqdnyggyedo

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I couldn't find any attribute for `labelPosition="bottom"` in [angular-material-stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview).
but it can help you

`<mat-horizontal-stepper  ngClass="mat-stepper-label-position-top"` 
`....`
`</mat-horizontal-stepper>`

In `style.css` add this code

`.mat-stepper-label-position-top .mat-horizontal-stepper-header{
  flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
}`

`.mat-stepper-label-position-top .mat-horizontal-stepper-header .mat-step-label{
  height: 48px;
}`

`.mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header:not(:first-child)::before, 
.mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header:not(:last-child)::after{
  bottom: 36px !important;
  top:unset !important;
}`